# Angular - URL is updating on state.go but the view is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a page to change to the same state on a click of an arrow but to update to a new object item that represents a new slide in the view.

However with my code below I get the url change but the view does not update.

The weird thing is.. this only seems to happen on the first slide so if I was to click the arrow to the next question it wouldn't update but if I refreshed the page it would and I can click through to the other questions.

Another instance of this working as it should is if I click a second,third or fourth item to take me to the slider and then if I click next from there as long as it isn't the first it'll go through to the next object item.

```
 // Index of the current item in the items array
    scope.itemIndex = assessment.test.items.indexOf(item._id);
    scope.numberOfItems = assessment.test.items.length;

// Checks if the index is not equal to the length of items
    if (scope.itemIndex !== scope.numberOfItems) {
        var nextItemId = assessment.test.items[scope.itemIndex + 1];
    }

// Checks if the index of the item is not greater than zero
    if (scope.itemIndex > 0) {
        var previousItemId = assessment.test.items[scope.itemIndex - 1];
    }

/**
 * Go to the next question
 */
    scope.next = function () {
        state.go('app.main.3Col.results.details', { itemId: nextItemId, assessmentId: assessment._id }, { refresh: true });
    };

/**
 * Go to the previous question
 */
    scope.previous = function () {
        state.go('app.main.3Col.results.details', { itemId: previousItemId, assessmentId: assessment._id }, { refresh: true });
    };
```

Comment: Have you set `reloadOnSearch` in the state configuration? True is the default but make sure it hasn't been set false as that would stop a reload when navigating to the same state.

Answer (score 0):

try to use options reload

```
scope.next = function() {
  state.go('app.main.3Col.results.details', {
    itemId: nextItemId,
    assessmentId: assessment._id
  }, {
    reload: true
  });
};
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: Forcing a reload doesn't seem to do anything, any other ideas?

Comment: show me your app.js (how do you define the route) and the controller that assign to route 'app.main.3Col.results.details'

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. my bad.. i see what went wrong... I needed to pass the item through as a param as it wasn't updated to the next item. Doing the below change that are commented fixed my problem.

```
        // Checks if the index is not equal to the length of items
    if (scope.itemIndex !== scope.numberOfItems) {
        var nextItemId = assessment.test.items[scope.itemIndex + 1];
        var nextItem = assessmentItems[scope.itemIndex + 1];
    }

    // Checks if the index of the item is not greater than zero
    if (scope.itemIndex > 0) {
        var previousItemId = assessment.test.items[scope.itemIndex - 1];
        // I had to define the previous item and push it through
        var previousItem = assessmentItems[scope.itemIndex - 1];
    }

    /**
     * Go to the next question
     */
    scope.next = function () {
        state.go('app.main.3Col.results.details', { item: nextItem, itemId: nextItemId });
    };
```